# What is the probability $P(Y=y | X=x) $ in this case?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In given n balls {$1,2,3,4,...,n$}  in the jug, if I randomly take 2 balls **with the return** (Independent extractions) , and:
X - the minimum value of the two extractions.
Y - the maximum value of the two extractions.
How can if calculate this:
 $$P(Y=y | X=x) =?$$

Answer (score 1):

If you have token ball x, ball y must be one of the balls x,x+1,...,n. $\Rightarrow P(X=x)=\frac{n-x+1}{n}$.
If $x>y: P(Y=y\land X=x)=0$, because the mininmum can't be greater than the maximum.
If $x=y: P(Y=y\land X=x)=\frac{1}{n^2}$, because you have to take the same given ball to times.
If $x<y: P(Y=y\land X=x)=\frac{2}{n^2}$, because you have to take two given balls, but since $x\neq y$ you can take them in order $x,y$ or $y,x$.
$\Rightarrow P(Y=y|X=x)=\frac{P(Y=y\land X=x)}{P(X=x)}=
\begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } y<x\\ \frac{1}{n\cdot (n-x+1)} & \text{if }y=x\\ \frac{2}{n\cdot (n-x+1)} & \text{if } y>x
\end{cases}$